# Custom image field for articles in Joomla 1.6

Tags: php, image, content-management-system, joomla

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a image upload field for my articles in Joomla 1.6. I'm kind of surprised to see this is a built in feature. My knowledge of Joomla is limited, this is my first site using it. Can't find much on the subject :S

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can browse here: http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=image+uploader
Maybe your users must sign up to your site before they can upload images !